# What is Bodhicitta?

Tags: nirvana

What is Bodhicitta?

I recall reading that the "power" of it is what ends up making someone a Bodhisattva or Buddha. So my specific question is whether it is nirvana, and if it is qualitative, felt etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bodhicitta means *[awakening-mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhicitta)*, from 'bodhi' meaning awakening and 'citta' meaning mind or consciousness. In Mahayana Buddhism, three aspects liberate one from cyclic existence: the attitude of renunciation (which turns away from worldly attachments), the wisdom of emptiness (which sees object without grasping at intrinsic existence), and finally bodhicitta, which is the intention to help all sentient beings.

Bodhicitta is of [two types](https://bodhicaryavatara.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/two-types-of-bodhicitta/): first, the very intention and aspiration to free all sentient beings from suffering; second, the process and implementation of doing so. Bodhicitta is also categorized as [relative and absolute](https://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Bodhichitta), where relative bodhicitta implies a compassionate wish and striving to help others, and ultimate bodhicitta is seeing the empty nature of things. I believe this is linked with either training compassion or gaining compassion through wisdom.

There are various [ways](https://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Bodhichitta) of training bodhicitta. Among these, one may train the [four immeasurables](https://tricycle.org/magazine/four-immeasurables/): loving-kindness (wishing for others' well being), compassion (wishing to alleviate others' suffering), sympathetic joy (partaking in others' well-being), and equanimity (considering others equally). Other means exist in Buddhism to develop bodhicitta, as [*equalizing oneself and others*](https://thubtenchodron.org/2003/08/bodhicitta-preparation/), which involves going past the distinctions between persons via an understanding in emptiness. Also, [seeing all beings as one's mother](https://thubtenchodron.org/2003/05/parents-importance/) relies on an understanding of karma to conceive others as having helped us in past lives.

--

Relative to your question, bodhicitta is *not* nirvana as it relies on worldy attachment (i.e. compassion) to occur. I understand, though I'm unsure, that you're asking if it is felt or cognitive. Interestingly, the Dalai Lama has said its best to focus on *feeling* when generating compassion, after having produced reasons. And, I have read a scientific papers [1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26686556) [2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26762882) claiming the value of both motivational/affective aspects *and* cognitive aspects of compassion meditation. So, both components are clearly experienced in compassion.

More so, given that the [union](https://tricycle.org/magazine/what-weve-been-all-along/) of compassion and emptiness is the aim of the Mahayana, and that emptiness entails initially an analytical training, one might consider how compassion *merges* with cognitive processes to see the world differently. So, it is indeed felt *and* realized.

Finally, given emptiness is related to [non-duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondualism), I feel the separation between cognition and feeling is illusory, as everything is highly related via cause and effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: good answer, thanks! could use something more explicit for "felt and realized"

Comment: i'll accept, though i wish that ^^